# Need help with the Laplace Equation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Hello I'm John and I'm new here. I need help with the fundamental solutions with the [Laplace equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKy8q.jpg).

**First Question:** Can anyone explain how the chain rule gets Equation #3?

**Second Question:** Can anyone explain where Equation #4 comes from and compute the second order partial derivatives $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$, and $f_{yy}$?

Third Question: Can anyone also explain how Equation #4 equals zero?

Answer (score 0):

Those are differential operators in Equation #3 (meaning gadgets that take a function and differentiate it, returning a function), so to make sense of them, you need to use a test function. With $\eta = x + iy$ and $\xi = x - iy$, for any function $f$,
$$
\def\dd#1#2{\frac{d#1}{d#2}} 
\dd{f}{x} = \dd{f}{\eta} \dd{\eta}{x} + \dd{f}{\xi} \dd{\xi}{x} 
= \dd{f}{\eta} \dd{}{x}(x + iy) + \dd{f}{\xi} \dd{}{x}(x - iy) 
= \dd{f}{\eta} + \dd{f}{\xi}.
$$
Thus, at the level of operators,
$$
\dd{}{x} = \dd{}{\eta} + \dd{f}{\xi}.
$$
The calculation
$$
\dd{}{y} = i \, \biggl( \dd{}{\eta} - \dd{f}{\xi} \biggr) 
$$
is quite similar.

---

For Equation #4, substitute formulas from Equation #3:
$$
\begin{align*}
\dd{}{x} \dd{}{x} + \dd{}{y}\dd{}{y} 
&= \biggl( \dd{}{\eta} + \dd{}{\xi} \biggr) \biggl( \dd{}{\eta} + \dd{}{\xi} \biggr) 
+ i^2 \, \biggl( \dd{}{\eta} - \dd{}{\xi} \biggr) 
\biggl( \dd{}{\eta} - \dd{}{\xi} \biggr) \\ 
&= \biggl( \dd{}{\eta}\dd{}{\eta} + 2\dd{}{\eta}\dd{}{\xi} + \dd{}{\xi}\dd{}{\xi} \biggr) 
- \biggl( \dd{}{\eta}\dd{}{\eta} - 2\dd{}{\eta}\dd{}{\xi} + \dd{}{\xi}\dd{}{\xi} \biggr) \\
&= 4\dd{}{\eta}\dd{}{\xi}. 
\end{align*}
$$